# How to find the p, q and d parameters for ARIMA given a model equation?

Tags: time-series, arima

I have the equation 
$$
Y_t = 1/2 Y_{t-1} + 1/2 Y_{t-2} - 1/3 \varepsilon_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t
$$
and I want to find the parameters p, q, and d.
Can somebody explain how I can know what the parameters are given an equation?

Comment: Have a look at http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p= maximum lag on Y  ... 2 in your case
q= maximum lag on the errors e  ...  1 in your case
d= 0

if the coefficient for lag1 is positive and is equal to the coefficient for lag2 
as in your case then p=1 d=1 and q=1

In general things get a little bit more complicated.

Comment: just to clarify, you mean I have a ARIMA(1,1,1)?

Comment: I mean p=q=d=1, right?

Comment: yes .............